# Differential system $y'=M(x)y$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $M:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}^{2x2}$ with   $M(x) =
\begin{pmatrix}
x^2 & 1 \\
0 & \frac{1}{x} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$
We have $y'=M(x)y$ with $x \in (0, \infty)$. I want to get ($\phi_1$, $\phi_2$) with $\phi_1(1) = (1, 0)$ and $\phi_2(1) = (0, 1)$ of this differential system but I don't know how.

My attempt:

Let $y$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$ then we have $\begin{pmatrix}
y_1' \\
y_2' \\
\end{pmatrix}
$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
x^2 & 1 \\
0 & \frac{1}{x} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$  $\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Thus we have $\begin{cases} 
y_1' = x^2y_1+y_2 \\ 
y_2' = \frac{1}{x}y_2 \\ 
\end{cases}$

Now I tried to solve the differential equation: $y_2' = \frac{1}{x}y_2$ but since we have $\phi_1(1) = (1, 0)$ and $\phi_2(1) = (0, 1)$ I am not sure how to solve the integrals correctly.

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, thus $F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{x} dx = ln(x)-ln(x_0)$

Do we have a $x_o$ given or did I chose a wrong path?

Comment: Hint: write $y = \binom{a}{b}$, then you have the scalar equation $b^\prime = \frac{1}{x} b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have a matrix only means you have a system of coupled differential equations that is written in a nice and compact way. Specifically, in your case

$$\begin{cases}y_{1}^{\prime}=x^{2}y_{1}+y_{2}\\y_{2}^{\prime}=\frac{1}{x}y_{2}\end{cases}$$

where $y=\begin{pmatrix}y_{1}\\y_{2}\end{pmatrix}$. The second equation can be easily solved for $y_{2}$ by means of separation of variables

$$\frac{{\rm d}y_{2}}{{\rm d}x}=\frac{1}{x}y_{2}$$

$$\int\frac{{\rm d}y_{2}}{y_{2}}=\int\frac{{\rm d}x}{x}$$

$$\ln |y_{2}|=\ln |x|+\ln |A|$$

$$y_{2}=Ax$$

where $A\in\mathbb{R}$ is just a constant. Then substitute its solution into the first equation

$$y_{1}^{\prime}=x^{2}y_{1}+Ax$$

and solve for $y_{1}$.

Comment: $\phi_1$ involves the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: What does $ln(A)$ mean?

Comment: Is it important to write $ln(A)$ or can we just say $ln|y_2|$ = $ln|x|$ implies $y_2 = x$ ?

Comment: @Maddude $\ln |A|$ is the integration constant. Without it, your solution is not general. You can find it given $y(x=1)$.

Comment: Ok, so $\phi_1(1) = (1, 0)$ and $\phi_2(1) = (0, 1)$ have to impact on the integrals?

Comment: @Maddude You should use those to find the constants.

Comment: @Gribouillis Interesting remark : could you say more about it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Well, [yes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x+exp(-x%5E3%2F3))!

Comment: Thanks, @Griboullis, I should have thought about it : using its definition $\partial\gamma(s,x)/\partial x=x^{s-1}e^{-x}$...

Comment: How would I solve the first equation? I know the technique with the variation of constants only if theres a $x_0$ and $y_0$